# How to fix a matrix value when running updateMatrixInput function in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

The below simple MWE code reflect changes to (a) slider input for periods (X) and (b) matrix inputs for the X variable (for periods, linked to the slider input above it) and a Y variable, in a plot to the right in the main panel. Default values, at inception, for X = 60 and Y = 0.20.

Works fine EXCEPT that when the Y variable in the matrix input is changed from the default 0.20, subsequently moving the slider input resets that Y variable back to 0.20. How would I fix this, so that the Y variable remains static (remaining that changed value) rather than reverting back to default value when the input slider is moved?

Code:

```
library(shiny);library(shinyMatrix);

matrix2.input <- function(x,y,z){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(y,z),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")} 

matrix.validate <- function(x,y){
  a <- x                                
  a[,1][a[,1]>y] <- y                   
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE])
  b[b<=0] <- NA
  b <- c(1,b)
  a <- cbind(a,b)
  a <- na.omit(a)
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]
  return(a)}

vector <- function(X,Y,Z){                                            
  a <- rep(NA, X)
  a[Y] <- Z
  a[seq_len(min(Y)-1)] <- a[min(Y)]
  if(max(Y) < X){a[seq(max(Y)+1, X, 1)] <- 0}
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)],seq_along(a))$y
  b <- seq(1:X)
  c <- data.frame(X = b, Z = a)
  return(c)}

vector.final <- function(x,y){vector(x,matrix.validate(y,x)[,1],matrix.validate(y,x)[,2])}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("periods","Nbr periods (X):",min=1,max=120,value=60),
      matrix2.input("vector_input",60,.2)
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(plotOutput("graph1")) 
  ) # close page with sidebar
    
server <- function(input,output,session)({
 
  periods <- reactive(input$periods)
  vector_input <- reactive(input$vector_input)
  
  observeEvent(input$periods,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,"vector_input", 
                      value=matrix(c(input$periods,0.2),1,2, 
                                   dimnames=list(NULL, c("X","Y")))
    ) # close update matrix
  }) # close observe event
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot({plot({vector.final(periods(),vector_input())})})
   
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `matrix` function embedded in the `updateMatrixInput` function embedded in the `observeEvent` in the `Server` section of the above code (ok, the 7th line of code from the bottom), replace the value of 0.2 with `input$vector_input[,2]`. This cleared up the error for me.